# pandas group by aggregate with Q1 and Q3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a sample dataset generated from this command

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": list(range(1, 21))}, "B": ["a"]*10 + ["b"]*10})
```

So ,my data looks like this

```
A   B
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   a
5   a
6   a
7   a
8   a
9   a
10  a
11  b
12  b
13  b
14  b
15  b
16  b
17  b
18  b
19  b
20  b
```

I would like to get the output group by column B for the first quantile (Q1) and the third quantile (Q3).  The expected output should be

```
B     Q1     Q3
a   3.25   7.75
b  13.25  17.75
```

I tried to do group by aggregation as follows

```
df.groupby("B").agg({"A": np.quantile(0.25), "A": np.quantile(0.75)})
```

but it does not work because np.quantile requires to parse input array and threshold.  May I have your suggestions how to get the expected output?  I would like to apply to the real data which is quite large.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and rename columns:

```
df1 = (df.groupby("B")['A']
         .quantile([0.25, 0.75])
         .unstack()
         .rename(columns={0.25:'Q1', 0.75:'Q3'}))
print (df1)
      Q1     Q3
B              
a   3.25   7.75
b  13.25  17.75
```